# Number of solutions of a system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I'm preparing for the ACTM State contest, and I stumbled across this question.

Determine the number of solutions in the system of equations:

\begin{align*}
-x+6y-3z &= -8\\
x-2y+2z &= 3\\
3x+2y+4z &= -6.
\end{align*}

I know how to solve a system of equations, but I was wondering if anyone knows a shortcut to this problem. Is there any way of telling how many solutions a system has without actually solving it?

Comment: Normally, a system of equations has one solution.  If they ask you how many solutions it has, you should suspect that it is not one of the normal cases.

Comment: What do you mean by "normally"? Consider the system
$$ x = 0 \\ x = 1 $$, which definitely has no solution at all...so the term "normally" in this context doesn't make sense in my opinion...

Answer (score 1):

adding the first two equations we obtain:
$$4y-z=-5$$
multiplying the first equation by $3$ and adding to the third we have
$$20y-5z=-30$$
dividing by $5$
$$4y-z=-6$$
thus our System has no Solutions.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question asked. They said they know how to solve and seemed wanted a general result. Not a specialized ad hoc method.

Comment: this isn't an ad hoc method

Comment: It isn't? [extra filler characters]

Comment: this answers exactly the given question

Comment: Disinformation...   guess that makes your question correct doesn't it. Have a wonderful Easter.

Comment: have a wonderful Easter too

Comment: This system has no solution because the determinants of the coefficients is zero. This is why there is no inverse matrix, etc, etc...